# What is the simplest way to stash a unique_ptr on the heap?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Long time Java, first time C++.

I'm writing a Java class that wraps an existing C++ API and looks something like this:

```
public class Foo implements Closeable {

    private long handle;

    public Foo(File file) {
        this.handle = Foo.openFile(file.toString());
    }

    // other methods go here...

    public void close() {
        Foo.closeFile(this.handle);
        this.handle = 0;
    }

    private static native long openFile(String file);
    private static native void closeFile(long handle);
}
```

We will stuff the pointer to the native C++ object into the `handle` field.

The problem is that the C++ library doesn't give me a pointer, it gives me a `unique_ptr<Foo>`. So this has to be moved onto the heap in `openFile()` (so it doesn't go out of scope), and then destroyed in `closeFile()`.

I'm having trouble getting this to work, and am not sure if I'm doing it properly. What is the simplest/cleanest way to do this correctly in C++?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
// This holds a unique_ptr<T>, typically on the heap, until no longer needed
template <class T>
class PointerHolder {
public:
    PointerHolder(unique_ptr<T> ptr) {
        this->ptr = std::move(ptr);
    }
    T * get() const {
        return this->ptr.get();
    }
private:
    unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};

// Holder for a Foo
typedef PointerHolder<Foo> FooHolder;

jlong JNICALL
Java_Foo_openFile(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jstring file)
{
    ...

    // Get smart pointer to native object from provided C++ library
    unique_ptr<Foo> ptr = ...

    // Save pointer on the heap until closeFile() is invoked sometime later
    const FooHolder *const holder = new FooHolder(std::move(ptr));

    // Return pointer encoded as a Java long
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(holder);
}

void JNICALL
Java_Foo_closeFile(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong handle)
{
    // Delete pointer holder, and by extension, storage object
    delete reinterpret_cast<FooHolder *>(handle);        // CRASH HERE
}
```

Is this correct? If so, can it be simplified?

In any case, right now the program is crashing in `closeFile()`, but I can't tell if it's crashing because I'm doing something wrong or there is some bug in the library I'm using (it's relatively new and buggy).

Thanks for any "pointers".

Comment: You should check if ``handle`` is nil or not before deleting or not

Comment: @Asesh it's legal (and a harmless no-op) to call delete on a NULL pointer in C++.  If the delete line is crashing, it's because its argument is a non-NULL but also invalid pointer.

Comment: An owning pointer to a `std::unique_ptr` is basically the same as not having a `std::unique_ptr` and just using a *raw pointer*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be simplified.

Since you have to integrate with Java's lifetime management, `unique_ptr` isn't doing you any favors.  You might as well manage the lifetime of the `T` object directly, instead of a wrapper for it (and certainly not a `FooHolder` wrapper for a `unique_ptr` wrapper for a `T` -- that's way too much wrapping).

Just call `release()` on the `unique_ptr<T>` to get a `T*` that needs to be `delete`-d when you are done with it.

Comment: So what I have is not optimal, but correct, so there must be a bug in the library - right? Also, isn't it possible the `unique_prtr` has a custom deleter that should be used, which would get lost if we just `release()` the pointer and then invoke regular `delete ptr` later?

Comment: @Archie: Unlike `shared_ptr` which can hold an arbitrary custom deleter, in `unique_ptr` deleter customization is part of the type.  If you aren't being given a `unique_ptr<T, CustomDeleter>` then you have a default deleter.

Comment: @Archie: And the bug could be in the consuming Java code, for example if it calls `close()` while another thread is actively using the object.  I don't see anything wrong with the wrapper, though.